# Is there an elegant way to run some code after the template for a component is loaded in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I am new to ES6 and Aurelia. I would like to execute some code after a template for a component loads. What I'm trying to do is get the page down editor working inside an Aurelia component. The imports seem to work for the most part (although Sanitizer doesn't seem to be imported), but I'm not sure how to run my initialization code *after the template loads.*

```
import 'Markdown.Converter'
import 'Markdown.Sanitizer'
import 'Markdown.Editor'

export class AddProject {
    constructor(){

    }
}
```

---

```
// initialization code
var converter1 = new Markdown.Converter();//Markdown.getSanitizingConverter(); // commented out doesn't work
var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
editor1.run();
```

**I just want to run my initialization code for the template after it get's loaded into the dom.** Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `attached`

```
export class MyClass{
    attached(){
        alert('My template is attached');   
    }        
}
```

Comment: What if i want to attach external javascript file in all pages? One way is to write attach() function for all pages and importSystemjs in to this. Is there any other solution for my problem?